# indexOf in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexof

Is there anyway to get indexOf like you would get in a string.

```
output.add("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10);  
String bigger[] = output.get(i).split(" ");
int biggerWher = bigger.indexOf("10");
```

I wrote this code but its returning an error and not compiling! Any advice ?

Comment: Hope you have specific programming language?

Comment: Looks like Java to me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is Java's Array indexOf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use this ...

```
output.add("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");  
String bigger[] = output.get(i).split(" ");
int biggerWher = Arrays.asList(bigger).indexOf("3");
```

Comment: What are the collateral effects by using asList? Is made a copy of original array on memory?

Comment: @Richard: It will create a new ArrayList object and converts from the String array, I'd guess 3-5 times the amount of memory than before.
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... array) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(array);
    }

Answer (score 13):

When the array is an array of objects, then:

```
Object[] array = ..
Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(someObj);
```

Another alternative is [`org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.indexOf(...)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) which also has overloads for arrays of primitive types, as well as a 3 argument version that takes a starting offset.  (The Apache version should be more efficient because they don't entail creating a temporary `List` instance.)

Comment: Why do I keep forgetting that most collection-methods apply to arrays too by using `asList`.... +1

Comment: What are the collateral effects by using asList? Is made a copy of original array on memory?

Comment: @Richard - No copy is made.  The 'asList' List is a wrapper for the original array.  Read the javadocs!!

Answer (score 4):

Arrays do not have an `indexOf()` method; however, `java.util.List` does. So you can wrap your array in a list and use the `List` methods (except for `add()` and the like):

```
output.add("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");  
String bigger[] = output.get(i).split(" ");
int biggerWhere = Arrays.asList(bigger).indexOf("10");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(array, item);` 
That will give you an index of the item, if any...

Please note, however, that the array needs to be sorted before searching.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct indexOf method in Java arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
output.add("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");
```

you miss a `"` after 10.