# checking a string in array

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, how can I test if an Array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

I want to check for a string `S` whether it is present in `string array` or not. Is there any direct method to do  so ?

**EDIT**

If the answer excludes the use of `List` then that would be better.

Comment: If by *"direct"* you mean a one-liner, then no.  `ArrayList` and some other collections have a `contains()` method that absracts away the details.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson i could use `indexOf()` for this. but i have to check all the rows in column number 0 in the 2-D String array against a string. Is there any way i can use `indexOf` with it ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this using the Arrays utility class.

If the array is not sorted:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(theArray).indexOf(o)
```

If the array is sorted, you can make use of a binary search for performance:

```
java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(theArray, o)
```

See here [Where is Java's Array indexOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof)

Comment: or even simple `Arrays.asLIst(array).contains(key)`

Comment: i want to check the first column for a 2-d array

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to List and check: Arrays.asList(arrayVariable).contains(S)