# How to find array ID?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to find array ID ?

for example:

```
String[] ar = {"ABC","EFG","HIJ"};
```

When search string will be "A" and it will show ABC but how to understand what Place in array has ABC 
(`ar[n]`, how to find ABC n ?)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof

Comment: Is you array sorted (as your example suggests)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find elements that *starts* with A:

```
for (int index = 0; index < ar.length; index++) {
  if (ar[index].startsWith("A")) {
    System.out.println("Found an element on array that starts with 'A': " + ar[index]);
  }
}
```

To find elements that *contains* A:

```
for (int index = 0; index < ar.length; index++) {
  if (ar[index].contains("A")) {
    System.out.println("Found an element on array that contains 'A': " + ar[index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: search string is `A` not ABC

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (ar[i].contains("A")) {
        System.out.println("found an element: " + ar[i] + " at index " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option in the other answer, or you can simply use an ArrayList. ArrayLists are dynamic, and you can call the indexOf() method and pass in "ABC". This will either return -1, if "ABC" is not present, or the index of "ABC". :)

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding correctly you're trying to find the index (not ID) by String. For example, you know "EFG".

Fot that you can use the code:

```
String[] str = {"ABC", "EFG", "HIJ"};

int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i].equals("EFG")) {
        index = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`for (String s : ar) {
if (s.startsWith("A")) {/* You code here */}}`

Should be :-

```
for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
        if(ar[i].startsWith("A")){
            System.out.println("Found in index " + i);
        }
}
```

Comment: That's a perfect example of a loop which doesn't allow to know the index of the found element, which is precisely what the OP is asking.

Comment: I think it should not be the enhanced loop, since you cannot get the index, did not notice that in the question.