# How to get an specific extract from a String?

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to get an extract from a String. The extract should contain the 2 words in front of the keyword and the 2 words behind the keyword. If the 2 words doesn't exist, the sentence should just end.

**Example:**

The word im looking for is *"example"*.

**Existing Strings:**

```
String text1 = "This is an example.";
String text2 = "This is another example, but this time the sentence is longer";
```

**Result:**

`text1` should look like this:

> is an example.

`text2` should look like this:

> is another example, but this

How can I do this?

Comment: Regex or use `split`, [search for the index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160832/how-to-find-index-of-string-array-in-java-from-a-given-value) and then print the result with get found index and its neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Pattern:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text1 = "This is an example.";
        String text2 = "This is another example, but this time the sentence is longer";
        String key = "example";
        String regex = "((\\w+\\s){2})?" + key +"([,](\\s\\w+){0,2})?";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text1);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        matcher = pattern.matcher(text2);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

output:

> is an example
>
> is another example, but this

mayby you will need to change regex a little bit, but you can try with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Using `replaceAll()`, you can do it in one line:

```
String target = text1.replaceAll(".*?((\\w+\\W+){2})(example)((\\W+\\w+){2})?.*", "$1$3$4");
```

fyi, `\w` means "word character" and `\W` means "non word character"