# How can I convert this JOptionPane result to integer value?

Tags: java, swing

How can I make this `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` return an integer value instead of a string value?

The values ​​of the chains are in Spanish sorry in advance

I put `Integer.parseInt()` and it didn't work for me*

```java
String[] Options = {
    "Mostrar la lista de ganancias de cada una de las busetas\n",
    "Mostrar la buseta que más dinero gano esa semana\n",
    "Mostrar la buseta que menos dinero gano esa semana\n",
    "Mostrar el dia que mas gana cada una de las busetas\n",
    "Aumentar las ventas que estan por debajo del promedio un 20%"
};
    
int decision = Integer.parseInt(
                                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "Digite la funcion que desea usar: ",
                                    "Busetas",
                                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                    null,
                                    Options,
                                    Options[0]));
```

Comment: Hi, improved readability will encourage people to answer your question by providing readers with a better experience up front. I've formatted your question for you but on your next ones, read up on stackoverflow markdown formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach would be to try and understand the method you're using by checking [the Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-)

1. First thing that I noticed, is your code will not even compile because you have too many parameters.

```java
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                            null, // parent
                            "Digite la funcion que desea usar: ", // message
                            "Busetas", // title
                            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, // ???? What's this?
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, // message type
                            null, // icon
                            Options, // selection values
                            Options[0]); // initial selection
```

2. Next, according to the Javadocs, `showInputDialog()` returns type `Object`.

That return value is what you're passing to `Integer.parseInt(String)`. Again, this will not compile, since `parseInt` expects a `String`. `Object` does not automatically cast to `String`. `parseInt` is also in the javadocs, or your IDE will tell you about this error.

3. If you make your code work step-by-step to try and understand what is happening, you'll see that `showInputDialog` returns the full `String` that the user selected from the dropdown. These come from your `Options` array. None of those can be directly translated to `int`:

```java
// Use small first letter in variable names. This is java convention and will help readers of your code be less confused.
String[] options = {
    "Mostrar la lista de ganancias de cada una de las busetas\n",
    "Mostrar la buseta que más dinero gano esa semana\n",
    "Mostrar la buseta que menos dinero gano esa semana\n",
    "Mostrar el dia que mas gana cada una de las busetas\n",
    "Aumentar las ventas que estan por debajo del promedio un 20%"
};

Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "Digite la funcion que desea usar: ",
                                    "Busetas",
                                    // JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, // Removed this to make it work
                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                    null,
                                    options,
                                    options[0]);

System.out.println(selection); // This prints for example: Mostrar la lista de ganancias de cada una de las busetas
    
// Therefore below line will be like Integer.parseInt("Mostrar la lista...");
int decision = Integer.parseInt(selection);
```

So you can see now why `Integer.parseInt()` did not work.

4. My suggestion is look up how to find the index of a String within a String array: [How to find index of STRING array in Java from a given value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160832/how-to-find-index-of-string-array-in-java-from-a-given-value)

TLDR: Your code doesn't compile. Refer to the Javadocs. Simplify your problem by taking smaller steps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I attach the solution and explanation of the change I made in the code in case someone needs it

```
String[] options = {
        "Mostrar la lista de ganancias de cada una de las busetas", 
        "Mostrar la buseta que más dinero gano esa semana", 
        "Mostrar la buseta que menos dinero gano esa semana",
        "Mostrar el dia que mas gana cada una de las busetas",
        "Aumentar las ventas que estan por debajo del promedio un 20%",
        "Salir"};

Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null, 
            "Seleccione una de las opciones disponibles", 
            "Busetas",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[0]);
    
decision = Arrays.asList(options).indexOf(selection);
```

I made use of the java.util.Arrays library
after this, I take the asList () method that returns us a list of fixed size backed by the specified array, in this case, it is the options array then I use the .indexOF () method to return an integer value depending on the selection and assign it to the decision variable

Comment: Congratulations on learning markup and following Java naming conventions!