# How to get string index of JSONArray?

Tags: java, arrays

For example I have JSONArray of strings:

```
["hello", "dear", "community"]
```

and I want to get index of "dear". How would I do that?

I am iterating over an array and want to check is array element in my JSONArray and get its index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is Java's Array indexOf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof)

Comment: you can use JSONArray.indexOf("dear") method.

Comment: @Charvee does JSONArray have such a method? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: Ya it has. I have tried it in my code.

Comment: See this I am using other jar.http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way of getting that. Unless you loop through the objects and find the index for the matching string.

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++) {
            if("dear".equals(arr.get(i))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am iterating over an array and want to check is array element in my JSONArray and get its index.

Comment: @onskulis The code Hirak provided does exactly that.

Comment: @Zeeker sorry I mean fast enumeration.

Comment: @Hirak thank you for solution, sorry for misunderstanding. It works perfectly, just needed to use it as a function.