# Cannot invoke indexOf on an Array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, indexof

I'm writing a method to calculate the distance between 2 towns in a given array by adding all the entries between the indexes of the two towns in the second array, but I can't invoke indexOf on the first array to determine where the addition should start. Eclipse is giving me the error "Cannot invoke indexOf on array type String[]" which seems pretty straight forward, but I do not understand why that won't work. 
Please note the program is definitely not complete.

```
public class Exercise_3 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Sets the array 
    String [] towns={"Halifax","Enfield","Elmsdale","Truro","Springfield","Sackville","Moncton"};
    int[] distances={25,5,75,40,145,55,0};
    distance(towns, distances, "Enfield","Truro");
}
public static int distance(String[] towns,int[] distances, String word1, String word2){
    int distance=0;
    //Loop checks to see if the towns are in the array
    for(int i=0; i<towns.length; i++){
        if(word1!=towns[i] || word2!=towns[i] ){
            distance=-1;
        }
    //Loop is executed if the towns are in the array, this loop should return the distance 
        else{
            for(int j=0; j<towns.length; j++){
                *int distance1=towns.indexOf(word1);*


            }
        }                               
    }
    return distance;
}
}
```

Comment: arrays dont have an `indexOf` method.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, arrays do not have any methods you can invoke. If you want to find the index of an given element, you can replace `String[]` by `ArrayList<String>`, which *has* an `indexOf` method to find elements.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because *Java* is not *JavaScript*.

The latter offers an `array` prototype that actually exposes the function `indexOf`, while the former does not.

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JavaScript are completely different from their [counterparts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in Java.

Anyway, you can be interested in the `ArrayList` class in Java (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for further details) that is more similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

How about this (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof))?

> There are a couple of ways to accomplish this using the Arrays utility class.
>
> If the array is not sorted:
>
> `java.util.Arrays.asList(theArray).indexOf(o)`
>
> If the array is sorted, you can make use of a binary search for performance:
>
> `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(theArray, o)`

I hope this helps you. If it doesn't, please downvote.