# Most efficient way to check if an array contains a value in Java?

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I have a similar logic for a method in a Java Class (not the real code, this is simplified for example purposes).

```
private Boolean method(Boolean booleanValue, SomeObject object) {
  return booleanValue ? Arrays.asList(object.getStringsArray()).contains("string") : false;
}
```

A collaborator who assigned himself to check the PR gave the following comment:

> This is inefficient. It is creating a new data structure only to iterate it and check if there is a certain string.

The `getStringsArray()` method returns a `String[]`, so will using a for-loop be better than `Arrays.asList()`?

Which way is more efficient to achieve this?

Comment: `Arrays.asList` just returns a wrapper, so that's not a problem. `object.getStringsArray` might be a problem, depending on what that does and whether there might be better ways to check for this string.

Comment: horrible method. the first argument is totally bogus.

Comment: I disagree with it being inefficient. `List` objects are backed by an array, so there is no performance loss. Even [the canonical answer for how to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4962413/5743988) uses this method.

Comment: We can't really say for sure whether your real code was good or bad, since it probably looked very different from this. Using `Boolean` instead of `boolean` here is a bad idea, and `Object` has no `getStringsArray` method.

Comment: Instead of a ternary operator, just use `return booleanValue && (code here);`

Comment: This is not the real code, is more like a pseudo-code, the real method doesn't looks like this, Im not able to post the original code here.

Comment: @4castle I thought about close-voting as a dup against that question, but the OP already has a working solution. I think this question is more about the efficiency of `Arrays.asList()` in particular, than how to search in general for a value in an array.

Comment: @azurefrog Perhaps, but the title is a bit misleading if someone were to search for this question. It would be nice if there was a banner at the top to point to the canonical answer. It's not a big deal though. I made sure it was seen in my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your co-worker is incorrect when they assert that your method is creating a new data structure.

If you look at the API for [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), it says that it

> Returns a fixed-size list **backed by the specified array.**

There is no reason to write your own code to iterate over the array when you can just wrap a `List` around it, and use its built-in methods.

Comment: Hey Thank you! I was worried because I can't come up with another solution. Now with the API documentation I have proof about this is the best method.

Comment: If you also want proof from another SO question, see [this popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1128728/5743988). This might actually be a duplicate of that question...