# Is there any structure to programmatically access indices of a String array in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a content provider for an Android app in Java and have a String array of constants and separate names for the index of each string in this array, as follows:

```
private static final String[] FILM_PROJECTION = {
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_FILM_ID,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_POSTER_URL,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_OVERVIEW,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_RATING,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_POPULARITY,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_VIDEOS,
    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_REVIEWS
};

private static final int COLUMN_FILM_ID_INDEX    = 0;
private static final int COLUMN_TITLE_INDEX      = 1;
private static final int COLUMN_POSTER_URL_INDEX = 2;
private static final int COLUMN_OVERVIEW_INDEX   = 3;
private static final int COLUMN_RATING_INDEX     = 4;
private static final int COLUMN_DATE_INDEX       = 5;
private static final int COLUMN_POPULARITY_INDEX = 6;
private static final int COLUMN_VIDEOS_INDEX     = 7;
private static final int COLUMN_REVIEWS_INDEX    = 8;
```

I'm thinking there's surely a better way to do this, and I tried it with `enum` e.g:

```
private enum FILM_PROJECTION_INDICES {
    FILM_PROJECTION
}
```

But Java doesn't unpack the String array so that doesn't work (despite all the values being constant). What I'm asking for is something like this:

```
index = FILM_PROJECTION.getIndexOf(FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_TITLE);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Enums work like plain classes, you can add methods and private fields to them. Store the index inside the enum and provide a getter to access it. Or use a Map.

Comment: wouldn't a Map fit your needs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Java's Array indexOf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FilmEntry` itself should already be an [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) (see [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)) with a custom `toString()` method:

```
enum FilmEntry {
    COLUMN_FILM_ID("Film Id"),
    COLUMN_TITLE("Title"),
    COLUMN_POSTER_URL("Poster URL"),
    COLUMN_OVERVIEW("Overview"),
    COLUMN_RATING("Rating"),
    COLUMN_DATE("Date"),
    COLUMN_POPULARITY("Popularity"),
    COLUMN_VIDEOS("Videos"),
    COLUMN_REVIEWS("Reviews");

    private String title;

    FilmEntry(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}

System.out.println FilmEntry.COLUMN_FILM_ID.toString(); // returns "Film Id"
System.out.println FilmEntry.COLUMN_FILM_ID.name(); // returns "COLUMN_FILM_ID"
System.out.println FilmEntry.COLUMN_FILM_ID.ordinal(); // returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum FilmType {

    FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_FILM_ID(0),
    ...
   ;

    private final int code;

    FilmType(int code) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}

index = FilmType.FilmContract.FilmEntry.COLUMN_FILM_ID.getIndex()
```