# Deleting duplicate strings in array

Tags: java, duplicates

At one point it compares array(1)compareto(array(1)) is this a problem? Amount birds is the amount of elements in array. I am trying to remove duplicate string in the array. Is it fixable or should i re approach.

```
for (i = 0; i <= amountBirds - 1; i++)
{
    for (x = 1; x <= amountBirds; x++)
    {
        duplicate = birdArray[i].compareTo(birdArray[x]);

        if (duplicate == 0)
        {
            birdArray[i] = birdArray[x];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `compareTo`, why not use `indexOf` to find the existing elements

Comment: Why not using `Set`?

Comment: Why not use Java Collection objects instead of an `array`? [Example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-count-duplicated-items-in-java-list/)

Comment: I had been out of touch with Java for years now. But I believe I used `indexOf` sometime back. Hava a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
birdArray = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(birdArray)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Hi I actually set birdArray as a global variable, im not exactly sure how i should word that, here it is: 
public static String[] birdArray = new String[50];

Comment: just put above code at place of your comparison for loops.

Comment: and add this lines in imports  --->          import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

Comment: :o it did something ill keep working at it thank you, it basically removed one of the elements in the array and also has a blank array element. But at same time does not accept duplicates if i enter one.

Comment: ya, HasSet can not have duplicates as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try Set or LinkedHashSet . Convert your arraylist into Set , It will automatically remove the duplicate from List as Set does not allow Duplicate value.  but Remember it is a Collection rather than a List.

Comment: I think i need a bit more resarch never heard of set or hashset aha.. but thank you

Answer (score 2):

Either you can include a if check before using compareTo method

```
if ( i != x ) {
        duplicate = birdArray[i].compareTo(birdArray[x]);
}
```

Or you can use Set in Java Collection library. This approach does not allow duplicate entries to be inserted. So at the time of insertion itself, you can avoid the duplicates.

Or you keep the birdArray as it is. And use a Set as a mediator to insert and remove the duplicates.

```
Set<String> birdSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); //to keep the order of the birds
for (i = 0; i < amountBirds; i++)
{
    birdSet.add (birdArray[i]);
}
birdArray = Arrays.copyOf(birdSet.toArray(), birdSet.size(), String[].class);
```

Comment: ahh i understand what you mean now, i like first option ill try and think aha