# Trying to find index of string in array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexof

I am trying to find the indexOf the longest string in the array, which is represented by the string longString. I keep getting a "cannot find symbol" error and have no clue how to fix this

```
public class Final21 {
       public static String getLongString(String[] array) {
          int x=0;
          int maxLength = 0;
          String longString = null;
          for (String s : array) {
              if (s.length() > maxLength) {
                  maxLength = s.length();
                  longString = s;
              }
          }
          return longString;
      }

         public static String getShortString(String[] array) {
          int minLength = 0;
          String shortString = null;
          for (String t : array) {
              if (t.length() > minLength) {
                  minLength = t.length();
                  shortString = t;
              }
          }
          return shortString;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};
             String longString = getLongString(names);
                System.out.println("The Longest String is: " + longString + " With The Index Of" + names.indexOf(longString));

             String shortString = getShortString(names);
                System.out.println("The Longest String is: " + shortString + " With The Index Of" );
      }

    }
```

Comment: What's the line number that you get the `Cannot find symbol` error?

Comment: Please try to be specific on the point from where you are getting the error. You could have done so, just by posting your compiler output here. If you do so, your question and answers also will be much more productive.. :)

Comment: @RomeoSierra Oh yea sorry... It was at names.indexOf. I'm new to stackoverflow lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem lies in `names.indexOf(longString)`. Because `names` is of type `String[]` which is an array. This type `String[]` **does not** have a method definition named `indexOf`. As an alternative you can try [`java.util.Arrays.asList(theArray).indexOf(o)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof#4962413)

So, to correct your code snip, you could rewrite it like

```
System.out.println("The Longest String is: " + longString + " With The Index Of" + java.util.Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(longString));
```

Read the JavaDoc for [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to brush up your knowledge on how to deal with arrays in java, using Java API.

Further, you can achieve the same by modifying the semantics of your code. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50166533/3126973) by [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) has done that for you. Read that as well..

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an `indexOf` function in arrays, instead of your current approach - I would return the `index` from the `getLongString` and `getShortString` methods; start by assuming it's the first element. If any element is longer (or shorter), update the return value. Like,

```
public static int getLongString(String[] array) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].length() > array[max].length()) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int getShortString(String[] array) {
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].length() < array[min].length()) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = { "bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack" };
    int longString = getLongString(names);
    System.out.println("The Longest String is: " + names[longString] + " With The Index Of " + longString);

    int shortString = getShortString(names);
    System.out.println("The Longest String is: " + names[shortString] + " With The Index Of " + shortString);
}
```

Which outputs

```
The Longest String is: tomtomjack With The Index Of 3
The Longest String is: bob With The Index Of 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of the indexOf() is:

> public int indexOf(char ch);

It returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1, if the character does not occur.

To get the required output.

You can try to change your code with following;

```
public static String getLongString(String[] array) {
     int x=0, maxLength = 0, index = 0;
     String longString = null;

     for (String s : array) {
         if (s.length() > maxLength) 
         {
             maxLength = s.length();
             index++;
             longString = s;
         }
     }
 return "The Longest String is: "+ longString + " With The Index Of :" + index;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};
       String longString = getLongString(names);
       System.out.println(longString);

 }
```

Comment: I tried @Romeo Sierra's solution and it seems to be working. Although your solution also works, it requires more lines of code.