# Why is the return type is not working for an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like the code below, to return the value of 'i' if the character is available in the array, if not I would like to return -1. However, Whenever I execute the code it returns -1 for both the conditions. Could you please guide me as to where I'm going wrong?

```
public class CharacterList {
  private char[] charArray;
  private int count;
  public CharacterList(int arraySize) {
    charArray = new char[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
      charArray[i] = ' ';
    }
    count = 0;
  }
  public int indexOf(char searchingChar) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
      if (charArray[i] == searchingChar) {
        a = i;
      } else {
        a = -1;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
}
```

Comment: JAVA is NOT JavaScript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Java's Array indexOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962361/where-is-javas-array-indexof)

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean why?

Comment: You probably mean `public int indexOf(char searchingChar) {
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) { if (charArray[i] == searchingChar)  return i; } return -1; }`

Comment: You can initialize `a` to `-1` and break when you find the right index (or you can follow hev1's answer, which is probably best).

Comment: Of follow my comment which is identical

Comment: @user My answer preceded the comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can initialize `a` to `-1` and break of the char matches

```
public int indexOf(char searchingChar) {
     a = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
      if (charArray[i] == searchingChar) {
        a = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting `a` to `-1` each time a character is not the char you are searching for. Instead, return the index when you find it and return `-1` at the end of the method.

```
  public int indexOf(char searchingChar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
      if (charArray[i] == searchingChar) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```